# Deploying cloud foundry on openstack: no route to host

Tags: cloud-foundry, openstack

I've been following the instructions for deploying `cloud foundry` on `openstack` and was having a problem with step that uploads the bosh stemcell:

```
$ bosh upload stemcell http://bosh-jenkins-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/bosh-stemcell/openstack/bosh-stemcell-latest-openstack-kvm-ubuntu.tgz

...
Error 100: Unable to connect to the OpenStack Compute API. Check task debug log for details. 
...
E, [2013-09-21T09:02:11.359958 #2587] [task:1] ERROR -- : No route to host - connect(2) (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH) (Excon::Errors::SocketError)
```

I can `ssh` to the instance running Micro Bosh and confirm that it can ping the compute host, but it can't connect via `tcp/http`.

I've described the error in more detail here:
http://openstack.redhat.com/forum/discussion/625/ingress-issue-from-spawned-instance-to-compute-host#Item_1

It appears to basically be an `openstack` `firewall/iptables` configuration issue between spawned instance running Micro Bosh and controller/compute host running the compute API, which I can only temporarily fix via `iptables`. But I was surprised not to find any other cloud foundry related posts pointing to this issue, and was wondering if anyone has seen this issue and found a workaround?

Comment: have you checked your security group rules?  you probably need to add a rule to open the port on the instance.

Comment: I did try adding rules but saw no impact. The instance can curl google.com and other nodes on my network, so there's no general issue with the instance traffic out (egress?). Only to compute host.

Comment: wait... are you trying to contact the compute host from the instance?

Comment: yes...the spawned instance tries to contact the compute service (that spawned it), all running on same VM/node...